# How to set value from the material ui date picker input field

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

```
<DatePicker
 value={props.openDate}
 onChange={props.handleInput}
 renderInput={(params) => (
 <TextField name="openDate" {...params} />
 )}
 />
```

I am not able to pick date from material ui date picker. If I specify name attribute in datepciker it throws error

> Type '{ name: string; value: any; onChange: any; renderInput: (params: TextFieldProps) => Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DatePickerProps<any, any> & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.
> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DatePickerProps<any, any> & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.

Why is that so?

```
const initialValues = {
    code: '',
    product: '',
    checked: 'false',
    jobCardNo: '',
    openDate: '',
    completionDate: '',
    serial: '',
    technicalNo: '',
    lineNo: '',
    show: false,
  };
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  const handleInput = (e: { target: { name: any; value: any } }) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

based on error message, property 'name' does not exist. You can try this.

```
    <DateTimePicker
    renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
    label="DateTimePicker"
    value={value}
    onChange={(newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    }}
  />
```

Comment: I had the above code to set the values. So can you please guide based on the above code.
The code has been added in code section. can you please look into that